# Dialogflow Integration With suggestion chip of Google assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es

I wish to know whether if I could integrate the Chatbot I made using dialogflow into my institute's webpage with the suggestion chips of Google assistant .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions work best when they address a concrete problem - something you've tried that doesn't seem to be working as you expect, and you can show source code, error messages, logs, screen shots, or other information to show you've tried to fix the issue, but are still running into problems. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

No, suggestion chips of Google Assistant are only compatible with Actions deployed on AoG. 
You can instead try to add follow-up dialogues, that will work as alternative for Suggestion Chips.